# How to convert IST datetime to specified datetime in React typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I want to convert a date string such as 2022-06-27T09:00:00 into PST timezone.
`(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)`

I'm first converting it to UTC:

```js
const dt = new Date("2022-06-27T09:00:00");
const utcdt = new Date(dt).toUTCString();
```

How to convert it to a specified timezone?

Comment: here you go : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat